# How do I add a logo in footer with Jupyter Notebook Metadata

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, metadata, reveal.js, rise

I couldn't find anything on this issue so I'm trying to raise this as a new question:

I work frequently present Jupyter Notebooks as slides using RISE, which presents notebooks as reveal.js slides. I know that RISE allows to adding headers, footers, and background images to slides by adding the following to the Notebook metadata:

```
{
 ...
 "rise": {
     "backimage": "mybackimage.png",
     "header": "<h1>Hello</h1>",
     "footer": "<h3>World!</h3>"
 }
}
```

This is good, but I'd like the image to actually be part of the footer (or at least position it to the bottom left).

Does anyone know a way to do add this other than having to manually add an image on every slide?

Thanks!

Paul

Answer (score 0):

The best way to position your logo relatively to your background image is to create a new background picture integrating the logo at expected position.

(Any Graphic software tool such as **GIMP** can do the tricks.)

Then you can use your new picture as the background.

---

Hope it helps,

Thomas